# Merge and rename: [airman-certification] and [licence]

Tags: discussion, support, status-completed, tag-synonyms

I can't tell the usage difference between [airman-certification](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/airman-certification) x116 and [licence](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/licence) x33.

The usage guidelines are:

> Airman Certification is for questions related to obtaining certificates and ratings for all flight crew members, mechanics, repairmen, aircraft dispatchers, and control tower operators. It includes required paperwork and testing, but not training (which would fall under [flight-training](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/flight-training)).

and

> Questions about various licenses needed for aviation. More specific tags should be used if possible.

... respectively.

Unless I'm missing something, I request merge and rename to [licenses-and-certifications](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/licenses-and-certifications).

---

Side notes:

1. Assuming [American English for tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/23873), licen**c**e needs to be license.
2. [airman-certification] may not be gender neutral.*

* Worth noting: the [FAA uses airmen](https://www.faa.gov/licenses_certificates/airmen_certification/) (plural), and Wikipedia uses "[pilot certification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pilot_certification_in_the_United_States)" for the FAA article, which omits the other professions: dispatchers, navigators, etc. But IMO the Wikipedia category name works best: [Aviation licenses and certifications](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Aviation_licenses_and_certifications), hence the request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think [pilot-certification](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pilot-certification) as per Wikipedia would be best since it clearly distinguishes between pilot and aircraft certification and is gender neutral language.

Comment: Now we just need mechanic-certification, atc-certification, dispatcher-certification, flight-engineer-certification, etc.  The one thing about airmen-certification is that it included more than just pilots!